# How to draw or describe Level curves of $x\ln (y^2-x)$

Tags: calculus

How to find the level curves of $$f(x,y)=x\ln (y^2-x)$$

If I had $f(x,y)=\ln (y^2-x)$, the level curves would have the equation $x=y^2-e^k$, which is a parabola with horizontal axis of symmetry. But now when I have $x$ that multiples on, I get stuck.

Comment: What do you mean with "$x$ that multiplies on"? When you fix $k$, you have a graph. Therefore, for a fixed $k$, $x=y^2 - e^k$ is a level curve. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/njpygyntxe

Comment: @MattiP. OP is talking about $x\ln(y^2-x)$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri ahaa, that wasn't very clear in the question definition.

Comment: Why not just solve $f(x,y)=k$ for $y$ (up to $\pm$) and plot the curve?

Comment: @MattiP: Actually it is!

Comment: I edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The level curves have the equation $x\ln(y^2-x)=k\in\Bbb R$. The point $(0,y)$ lies on the level curve only for $k=0$. For $k\ne0,x\ne0$.

For $k,x\ne0$, you can isolate $x,y$ as under:

$\displaystyle x\ln(y^2-x)=k\implies y^2=x+e^{\frac kx}\ (k,x\ne0)$

When $k=0$, you get the level curves $x=0\ne y,y^2=x+1$ in the $xy$ plane.

The level curves are $\begin{cases}\displaystyle y^2=x+e^\frac zx,&z\ne0\\x=0\ne y,y^2=x+1, &z=0\end{cases}$

Comment: I don't think that you should divide by $x$ or exclude 0 since it is inside the domain of the function. Or can you explain why you exclude 0?

Comment: @user575062 Please see the modified answer